# Qt quick applications glitching

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qt-quick

I opened some Qt quick examples that comes with Qt and when I try to resize the window it starts to glitch.

This is an animated gif using the stoc example:

[glitch http://105.imagebam.com/download/ZgcdXsQQukzkLCDchoYVrQ/44471/444703921/glitch.gif](http://105.imagebam.com/download/ZgcdXsQQukzkLCDchoYVrQ/44471/444703921/glitch.gif)

My configuration is: Windows 10, 6 GB ram, i5, and using Qt 5.5.1 64bit MSVC 2013.

Is there any way of fixing it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you try an OpenGL build of Qt (configure with `-opengl desktop`)?

Comment: I think that I'm compiling using the Qt 5.5.1 without OpenGL, I couldn't find it on the online installer, only for Qt 5.4. What you mean with configure with `-opengl desktop`?

Comment: I meant configure Qt with that argument before you build it. But [maybe you don't have to now](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html#dynamically-loading-graphics-drivers): you can set the `QT_OPENGL` environment variable to `desktop` before you run your application, and that should switch it to OpenGL from ANGLE at runtime.

Comment: It's possible that this a driver/hardware acceleration issue on your system

Comment: @sehe - I will run some tests and see if I can make it work and post here the results.

Comment: @Mitch - The Qt installed is the one that I downloaded using the online installer, I didn't build it myself, how can I configure using `-opengl desktop`? Do I have to compile Qt manually with this argument?

Comment: Just tested using Qt 5.4.2 64bit OpenGL and it's working properly. I think that I have to compile Qt 5.5.1 with OpenGL as it doesn't seems to have that version available to download yet.